# How to access groovy function inside sh in below jenkins pipeline script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, sh

```
def Greet(name) {
    echo "Hello ${name}"
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh """
                Greet('Build Team')
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to call 'Greet' function from the stage 'Test' inside the shell . But getting error as

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Check1@tmp/durable-ce807c1d/script.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `'Bob''
```

Any one let me know how we can call 'Greet' function from the stage 'Test' inside the shell .

Comment: Please paste the contents of `script.sh`

Comment: Since shell and Groovy are different languages, you can't directly invoke a Groovy function from shell. But maybe you are already happy, when the substitution of `Greet` is performed, before the shell script is started? If so, your question is only a groovy problem, unrelated to shell scripting, and you should update your question to make this point clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sh "${Greet('blah')}"
```